# Social CRM Content Display

Tags: lightning, socialpost, social-contacts

Is it possible to display Social CRM Content(Post to Facebook,Twitter) in salesforce lightning community? I have a requirement to share articles to Facebook/Twitter. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
You need to integrate Facebook, Twitter API into the Salesforce. 
Facebook has REST Api named Graph API where you can retrieve or update the Data to your facebook account.
Same as everyother Social Media has there own API.

[Developers Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)